# Consequences of no commit/acknowledge to Kafka after consuming a message (with auto commit disabled)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a multi-node Spring Boot application running on Kubernetes. Each node has 1 listener each. Since I have facing issues with auto commit while using spring-kafka, I have now switched to a `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` acknowledgement mode. [This is what helped me do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566465/how-to-commit-after-each-kafka-message-in-spring-kafka)

Now, I am acknowledging to Kafka at the end of the execution of my service. What would happen, if for some reason I am not able to acknowledge to Kafka? Will the listener read that message again after a cooldown? If yes, how can I control this cooldown period? If not, what happens to that message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener will not re-consume the message unless the consumer is restarted, or a rebalance occurs.

Kafka maintains 2 pointers for each consumer/partition; the `position` (last read record) and the committed offset. When a consumer starts, or a rebalance occurs, the position is set to the committed offset.  The position is only changed by fetching new records, or if a seek is performed on the consumer for that partition.

Comment: Assuming that commit did not occur due to some internal server error, how would you recommend to re-flow or re-accessing such messages? Does Kafka make it easy to replay/stream old messages?

Comment: You can stop/start the listener container or simply throw an exception and the default error handler will retry the failed record.